# How do I register a tap to the screen to restart the game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Everything I need are commented down below, I have a function that when I tap it, the game should restart. The restart function works by its self, but I only want it to restart after the user taps the screen. If you need some clearing up on what certain parts of the code do, just comment down below please Could you please let me know what I've done wrong, thanks!

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball = SKSpriteNode()
    var enemy = SKSpriteNode()
    var main = SKSpriteNode()

    var topLbl = SKLabelNode()
    var btmLbl = SKLabelNode()

    var score = [Int]()

    func pauseGame() { // PAUSE GAME FUCTION
        self.isPaused = true
        self.physicsWorld.speed = 0
        self.speed = 0.0
        self.scene?.view?.isPaused = true
    }

    func test(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) { // MY FUNC TO RESTART THE GAME
        let skView = self.view!
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        topLbl = self.childNode(withName: "topLabel") as! SKLabelNode
        btmLbl = self.childNode(withName: "btmLabel") as! SKLabelNode
        ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode

        print(self.view?.bounds.height)

        enemy = self.childNode(withName: "enemy") as! SKSpriteNode
        enemy.position.y = (self.frame.height / 2) - 50

        main = self.childNode(withName: "main") as! SKSpriteNode
        main.position.y = (-self.frame.height / 2) + 50

        let border  = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

        border.friction = 0
        border.restitution = 1

        self.physicsBody = border

        startGame()
    }

    func startGame() {
        score = [0,0]
        topLbl.text = "\(score[1])"
        btmLbl.text = "\(score[0])"
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10 , dy: 10))
    }

    func addScore(playerWhoWon : SKSpriteNode){

        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        if playerWhoWon == main {
            score[0] += 1
            ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 10))   
        }
        else if playerWhoWon == enemy {
            score[1] += 1
            ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -10, dy: -10))
        }

        if score[0] >= 10 {
            pauseGame()
            test() // HERE'S WHERE I TRY AND CALL THE FUNCTION, BUT IT's NOT WORKING     
        }
        else if
            score [1] >= 10 {
            pauseGame()
            test() // HERE'S WHERE I TRY AND CALL THE FUNCTION, BUT IT's NOT WORKING AGAIN
        }

        topLbl.text = "\(score[1])"
        btmLbl.text = "\(score[0])"
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { 
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            if currentGameType == .player2 {
                if location.y > 0 {
                    enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))
                }
                if location.y < 0 {  
                    main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))  
                } 
            }
            else {
                main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))
            } 
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            if currentGameType == .player2 {
                if location.y > 0 {
                    enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))
                }
                if location.y < 0 { 
                    main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))   
                }
            }
            else{
                main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))
            }  
        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered

        switch currentGameType {
        case .easy:
            enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 1.3))
            break
        case .medium:
            enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 1.0))
            break
        case .hard:
            enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 0.7))
            break
        case .player2: 
            break
        }

        if ball.position.y <= main.position.y - 30 {
            addScore(playerWhoWon: enemy)
        }
        else if ball.position.y >= enemy.position.y + 30 {
            addScore(playerWhoWon: main)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, `SKScene` conforms to `UIResponder` protocol since you're using `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` methods. The protocol also has `touchesEnded(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?)` method. 
Basucally you need to add something like:

```
override func touchesEnded(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?)
{
    let skView = self.view!
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

This method is invoked when user removes his finger from the screen after tapping the `GameScene` object.

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` as well. To do so however, you need to create an instance of it, declare your class as its delegate, add the view you want to tap into its collection and attach a method to it. I've never done this programmatically, only in the IB. The setup looks like so:

[image]

To add a tap gesture via code:

In your GameScene class:

```
weak var tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer!
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    tapGesture  = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:#selector(self.handleTap:)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture )
}
func handleTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    //restartLogic here
}
deinit{
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a-lot bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Skip the gesture recognizer.

Simply call the restart code from `touchesEnded` *if* the game is not in progress.

Comment: How do I do that? As in what code do I change, I'm a relative beginner

Comment: I would not recommend doing this approach,  it is a cheap quick solution that ends up placing more work on yourself if you decide to add other touch functionality to your game.  The gesture recognizer is most likely the best way to go

Comment: Sorry, but this is complete nonsense. This is the recommended way of handling touches in SKScene.

Comment: @T.BenjaminLarsen Recommended by who?  There is no "recommended" way of handling touches in Sprite Kit.  You use touchesEnded when you want to create quick interactivity with a sample/demo application, when you are ready to move on to handle more advance input handling, you do your best to avoid using touches ended because the code can become cluttered very quickly.

Comment: OK, recommended is perhaps a tad overblown, but The SKScene documentation specifically mentions implementing responder methods for touch-handling. 

Adding a tapGesture-recognizer to an SKScene is akin to adding one to a UIButton.

Comment: The documentation just mentions you may want to subclass the SKScene to handle touch, then it goes on to mention that you may want to delegate it to another class entirely.  TapGesture (and all gestures) still conforms to responder methods, the question you need to ask yourself is how to use it.  If you want to treat your screen as one big controller, use gestures,  if you want to actually interact with the scene and its children nodes, well then you need to evaluate your needs, and determine how to handle input.

Comment: Here is an example as to why I do not recommend this, because I see people doing this a lot.  You have multiple nodes on the scene with `isUserInteractionEnabled`.  If you poke any of those nodes, the scene responded code will not get called, so you are going to have to pass the touch call back to the scene, or disable `isUserInteractionEnabled` when you are in the state where you want to touch anywhere on the screen.

Comment: I think we’re moving of topic. Yes, you could do this in multiple ways but this is definitely among the most common patterns. Personally I’d probably have some sort of state-handler and not bother with interaction in the nodes if the game was ended. It should be fairly obvious that my reply wasn’t meant to inform any larger architectural pattern. It’s an easy solution to a fairly concrete problem that could easily be expanded upon.

Comment: Explain that in your answer and I will remove the downvote, it is why I do not like it.  A few months from now somebody is going to hit this answer and think that gestures should be skipped all together.